# I have a vod stream from wowza. I am streaming it using rtmp. I can receive the stream on vlc. can i receive the same stream on wowza?

Tags: rtmp, wowza

I have tried streaming on vlc. It works. Can I receive the same stream on wowza? If vod cannot be used, what are other ways to stream video from wowza server and receive the same stream on wowza?

Answer (score 0):

If you need an origin/edge **VOD** configuration you can use the [MediaCache](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?121-MediaCache-AddOn-package-for-multiple-server-video-on-demand-delivery-and-scalability) and `vod-edge` applications.

For a **Live** stream you can either do [Push Publishing](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?109-How-to-push-streams-to-CDNs-and-other-services-%28Push-Publishing%29) or use a [live stream repeater](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?227-How-to-configure-a-live-stream-repeater).

A third option is to create a **Live** stream based on static files using a custom Wowza module and the [Stream class](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?140-Stream-Class-Example).